# Let $f : X \to Y$ and g : $Y \to Z$ be bijective functions. Prove the following equations.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have these equations and I really don't know, what to do.

(i) $f^{-1}$ is bijective with $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f.$

(ii) $g \circ f$ is bijective with $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}.$

**My attempt:**

(i) $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f,$ because of the potency law $(x^m)^n = x^{m n}$

(ii)  Show $f$ is injective and surjective to be bijective. But how ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Its not ''functional-analysis".

Answer (score 2):

> (i) $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f,$ because of the potency law $(x^m)^n = x^{m\cdot n}$

No, that's not how it goes. The law doesn't even make sense in the context of functions (well, it somewhat does if both domain and codomain are the same, but it is really derived from the property to begin with so you'd still have a circular reference). For example if $f:X\to Y$ then what is $f^2$?

Forget about exponentiation. The $f^{-1}$ symbol **does not** mean exponentiation. It's just a symbol that says: "$f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$". In precise terms $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is a function such that $f\circ f^{-1}=id_{Y}$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=id_{X}$ where $id_A:A\to A$ is the identity, $id_A(x)=x$. It can be shown that any function has a unique inverse if it exists.

So have a look at those equations: $f^{-1}\circ f=id_X$ and $f\circ f^{-1}=id_Y$. It means that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$. But it also means that $f$ is the inverse of $f^{-1}$ because the definition is symmetric. In symbols we would write it down as $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$.

> (ii)  Show $f$ is injective and surjective to be bijective. But how ?

You don't have to show that $f$ is injective and surjective. You can show that $f$ has the inverse. It's often simplier and faster.

A function is invertible (i.e. it has the inverse) if and only if it is bijective. This is a set theoretic theorem and I'm sure you can find a proof in some book on the set theory. For example here: http://math.colorado.edu/~kstange/has-inverse-is-bijective.pdf

With that property lets have a look at the problem one more time:

> (ii) $g \circ f$ is bijectiv with $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}.$

Again, lets use the definition of the inverse:

$$f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}\circ g\circ f=f^{-1}\circ id\circ f=f^{-1}\circ f=id$$

Since the composition operator $\circ$ is associative. Thus

$$(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})\circ (g\circ f)=id$$

Analogously you show the other composition $(g\circ f)\circ(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})=id$ meaning $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g\circ f$. Or in symbolic notation: $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$.